# Aviso de gravado com sucesso no banco - R

Tags: r, postgresql

Olá! Atualmente estou gravando/atualizando minhas tabelas no banco com com a linguagem R:

`dbWriteTable(con, "tabela",tabela, row.names=FALSE, overwrite  = TRUE)`

Esse meu script que atualiza as tabelas em R em um banco postgres, é rodado automaticamente de tempo em tempo por uma task do windows.
Preciso saber quando essa informação é gravada ou não, talvez em formato de alerta na tela, ou algo que chame a atenção.

obs.: sei que existe o "r.out", mais ele sobrescreve, não avisa quando da problema, nem nada parecido.

Comment: O que busca exatamente? Manter um arquivo de log? Uma mensagem popup na tela do desktop? Enviar um email com aviso? Um SMS? Sempre que grava ou só quando ocorre erro? Tudo isso é possível.

Comment: Um pop-up na tela seria perfeito!

Answer (score 1):

Eis como gerar um arquivo de log simples, que grava a data e hora e qualquer eventual mensagem de erro:

```
logf <- file("exemplo.log", open = "a")
  writeLines(as.character(Sys.time()), logf)
  try(dbWriteTable(con, "tabela", tabela), outFile = logf)
close(logf)
```

Se precisa de um registro mais detalhado, veja `sink`, que redireciona a saída do terminal para uma conexão.

Para alerta de erro, pode usar `tryCatch` e executar um comando de sistema. Por exemplo, para avisar todos os usuários logados em um servidor *nix:

```
tryCatch(dbWriteTable(con, "tabela", tabela),
         error = system("wall 'Erro na gravação do DB'"))
```

Para uma mensagem na tela do seu ambiente gráfico, uma opção é o pacote svDialogs:

```
tryCatch(dbWriteTable(con, "tabela", tabela),
         error = svDialogs::msg_box("Erro na gravação do DB"))
```

Comment: Vou testar! Obrigado!